# Show Data Fast In RecyclerView [ Android Development with Kotlin ]

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

My application must show data from a Csv File in RecyclerView.
I have everything set up and I set up also a function to read the Csv File, but I have a problem.

Since the Csv File is very large ( many thousand of rows ) when I try to show all the rows in the RecyclerView, app crashes.

How can avoid this?

Ah, I enter the data in a Room database.

This is my process :

1. ReadFile
2. Save it as List of List of String
3. Create my type objects for every row and create a List
4. Apply insertAll(input : List) to insert into Room Database

How can I manage this type of operation without slowing down or crashing the application?

Thanks everyone and good life :)

Answer (score 0):

Best way to do that is by partitioning, load only 20 row each time or any number, when user scroll load another 20.